# Unable to fetch file as blob or raw blob from Gitlab using RESTful API

Tags: git, api, gitlab, restful-url

The [GitLab Docs](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/repository_files.html) mention the following API for fetching contents of a file from a repo:

> `GET /projects/:id/repository/files`

with the parameters as

> id (required) - The ID of a project
>   sha (required) - The commit or branch name
>   file_path (required) - The path the file

Here is my GET request

> `http://git.domain.com/api/v3/projects/7/repository/files?private_token=someToken&file_path=README.md&ref=master`

All I am getting is a 404.

There is another way to do it too as mentioned [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/repositories.html)

> `GET /projects/:id/repository/blobs/:sha`

with parameters as

> id (required) - The ID of a project
>   sha (required) - The commit or branch name
>   filepath (required) - The path the file

Heres my request:

> `http://git.domain.com/api/v3/projects/7/repository/blobs?private_token=someToken&filepath=README.md&ref=master`

And again I am getting the ugly 404
Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arises due to the difference in versions of the installed Gitlab and API.

You should use API compatible with your installed Gitlab instance which can be found here

> `http://your.domain.com/help`

Instead of using API docs provided by gitlabhq use the one that comes with your installation.
It can be found at

> `http://your.domain.com/help/api`